# Play JSON Implicit Resolution For Sealed Trait Types

Tags: scala, play-json

I have a sealed trait that is implemented by two case classes. I then wrote implicit Reads and Writes for these types like this:

```
  implicit val myCaseClassWrites: Writes[MySealedTrait] = Writes {
    case CaseClass1(a, b, c) => Json.toJson(
      a,
      b,
      c
    )
    case CaseClass2(a, b, c, d) => Json.toJson(
      a,
      b,
      c,
      d
    )
  }
```

When I used this in my Controller where I'm writing the response to a client as JSON, it fails compilation with the following error:

```
No Json serializer found for type com.mypackage.CaseClass2. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type
```

However, when I wrote an explicit Writes like this below:

```
  implicit val caseClass2JSONWrites: Writes[CaseClass2] = Writes { caseClass2 =>
    Json.toJson(caseClass2.a,
      caseClass2.b,
      caseClass2.c,
      caseClass2.d
    )
  }
```

It worked. Why is this? Any ideas?

Comment: This may be intentional but `Json.toJson(a,b,c)` will produce an array, not sure that's what you expect.

Comment: Case class and sealed trait are supported by macro generated Play JSON `Writes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somehow expected. You need to either:

1. cast your values to be of type `MySealedTrait`
2. or, explicitly declare the `Writes` for each case class

---

If you go for (1) this will look something like this:

```scala
Json.toJson((caseClassValue: MySealedTrait))
```

---

If you go for (2), you have to change your serializers like this:

```scala
implicit val myCaseClass1Writes: Writes[CaseClass1] = ???

implicit val myCaseClass2Writes: Writes[CaseClass2] = ???

implicit val myCaseClassWrites: Writes[MySealedTrait] = Writes {
    case c1: CaseClass1 => myCaseClass1.writes(c1)
    case c2: CaseClass2 => myCaseClass2.writes(c2)
  }
```

Maybe you don't actually need the serializer for the trait if you only ever serialize known case class subtypes.

Comment: You should be able to do `(caseClassValue: MySealedTrait)`, which will give a compile error if somehow you passed the wrong type, whereas `asInstanceOf` would result in runtime errors.